# Is Coulomb's law is applicable on electrons?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics, coulombs-law

Well, I know my question seems to be obvious, but I'm confusing with the fact that as coulomb's law follow newton third law of motion , that is following classical mechanics so how it can be applicable to electrons , as physics of nanoparticles like electrons, protons are governed or understood by the quantum mechanics not classical mechanics.

Comment: Coulomb's law applies to all stationary, point charges. A pair of point charges means that their size should be negligible in comparison to the distance between them. The charge radius of an electron is approximately 2.82 x 10^-15 m. So if you have two electrons separated by, say, 2 metres or so, you can safely call them point charges and ignore quantum effects.

Comment: However, if the electrons are too close to each other(I am not aware of the exact distance, however), quantum effects cannot be ignored. They tend to play a much more dominant role than classical mechanics. 
I think its really a matter of distance between them.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends where you look.

In atoms and solids one can treat electrons as quantum particles and fields as classical. This is called semi-classical approximation, as far as I remember. And it works well, i.e. it predicts what we observe. This is enough. You would expect this to be true on some level since quantum physics must reduce to classical physics as one transitions from microscopic to macroscopic world.

Having said that there are effects when one does need to quantize fields as well as electrons. Spontaneous decay in atoms is the first that comes to mind. What I mean is that, as far as I remember, one usually quantizes the field to explain spontaneous decay of atoms in excited states. But even then classical laws don't quite go away. At least in quantum optics, you end up with quantized field where field operators are still subject to something very similar to Maxwell's equations.

In summary I would say that there is no sharp classical quantum divide in practice, instead you have two extremes and a sea of various approximations between them that often work well in practice. It would seem to me that it is a hallmark of a good theoretician to know which approximation is likely to work well in which situation, and how to switch between them.

---

Also note that calling electrons small is not necessarily correct. I don't think there is anything theoretical limiting having electrons that occupy very large space. We don't observe it often in practice, but you can get electron beams with rather large coherence length (e.g. 200nm https://academic.oup.com/jmicro/article/70/1/3/5862540). Not meters like in case of photons, but on a scale of a virus, so 'large' :-)

Comment: Actually, a day before I started to study quantum mechanics, in the introduction of which it is clearly mentioned that as physicists notice that physics of nanoparticles can not clearly understood by the classical mechanics ,that generates the need of quantum mechanics which beautifully matches with the experimental results as well :) ,but thanks , I found your answer helpful.